# Ivy not ignored jars marked as exclusion in pom

Tags: pom.xml, ivy

This is my ivy.xml:

```
<dependencies defaultconf="default">
    <dependency org="com.mycompany" name="custom" rev="1.0"/>
</dependencies>
```

ivysettings.xml:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="repo.mycompany.com" />
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="repo.mycompany.com" root="http://repo.mycompany.com/maven/" m2compatible="true" usepoms="true" />
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Artifact com.mycompany:custom:1.0 created as maven pom and published to repo.mycompany.com:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>custom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                     <groupId>logkit</groupId>
                     <artifactId>logkit</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avalon-framework</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Wheh I download ivy libs with such code:

```
<target name="ivy-init">
    <mkdir dir="${internal-libs}"/>
    <ivy:settings file="${ivy.settings.dir}/ivysettings.xml"/>
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${internal-libs}/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" sync="true"  />
</target>
```

ivy download excluded deps avalon-framework:avalon-framework:4.1.3 and logkit:logkit:1.0.1

Why? I exluded it in pom!

How to exclude it with ivy, keeping the same simple ivy.xml?

Comment: which version of ivy are you using?

Comment: it could be this [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-974) which was fixed in 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve this in next steps:

1. review my pom.xml  and add exclusion to other artifact depends on
   commons-logging:commons-logging
2. update to latest ivy
3. clean local ivy cache

Comment: so it actually was the bug I posted? And you had an older version of ivy installed?

Comment: I have unclear dependency on my pom.xml. Unwanted avalon-framework was downloaded by common-beanutils via commons-logging